# Merge two lists of dictionaries with different keys

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have two lists of dictionaries.

```
list1 = [{'id': '1', 'name': 'one'},{'id': '2', 'name': 'two'}]
list2 = [{'age': '52', 'sal': '95'}, {'age': '37', 'sal': '86'}]
```

I want to merge these lists to get the following list:

```
list3 = [{'id': '1', 'name': 'one', 'age': '52', 'sal': '95'},{'id': '2', 'name': 'two', 'age': '37', 'sal': '86'}]

list1.extend(list2) hasn't given me the desired result.
```

Answer (score 2):

Mutability of dictionaries and `update` gives the answer needed, but stored in `list1`.

```
[lst1.update(lst2) for lst1, lst2 in zip(list1, list2)]
print(list1)
```

Comment: Using listcomps (a functional programming construct) for side-effects is terrible. If you want to do this in-place, just do `for d1, d2 in zip(list1, list2): d1.update(d2)` and avoid creating a pointless temporary `list` of `None`. Only use the listcomp if you are making new `dict`s without modifying the originals, e.g.`list3 = [{**d1, **d2} for d1, d2 in zip(list1, list2)]`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the dict.update() function to merge 2 dictionary objects inside the one that calls it:

```
a = {'id': '1', 'name': 'one'}
b = {'age': '52', 'sal': '95'}
a.update(b)
print(a) # {'id': '1', 'name': 'one', 'age': '52', 'sal': '95'}
```

Since you need to do this for every two corresponding dictionary elements at the same index in the 2 lists:

```
def mergeDictLists(list1, list2):
    result = [] 
    for i in range(len(list1)):
        a = list1[i].copy() # so that list1 elements are not modified by a shallow copy
        b = list2[i]
        a.update(b)
        result.append(a)
    return result

list1 = [{'id': '1', 'name': 'one'},{'id': '2', 'name': 'two'}]
list2 = [{'age': '52', 'sal': '95'}, {'age': '37', 'sal': '86'}]
list3 = mergeDictLists(list1, list2)
print(list3) # [{'id': '1', 'name': 'one', 'age': '52', 'sal': '95'}, {'id': '2', 'name': 'two', 'age': '37', 'sal': '86'}]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can `zip` the two lists and merge both dictionaries with `{**x, **y}`:

```
list3 = [{**x, **y} for x, y in zip(list1, list2)]
```